# Twitter Bootstrap - Stopping all responsive navbars on page dropping down?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of responsive navbars on a page, but when I click on the little icon which drops down the navbar all the navbars on the screen collapse. How I can prevent all navbars from collapsing when I only want 1 to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `stopPropagation()` with jQuery. See http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/. jQuery has a number of event handler methods such as `preventDefault()` which can be used to keep events from only hitting specific elements.